# Declaring variables in SQL and "Must declare the table variable @TBL" error

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic-sql

I would like to ask how to declare a table in MySQL. I tried using this code but I am getting the error below:

```
DECLARE @TBL VARCHAR(20)
SET @TBL = 'A171107001';

select APPLICATION, count(JOB_NAME) as 'JOB COUNT' from @TBL
```

Error Message:

> Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Must declare the table variable "@TBL".:
>   DECLARE @TBL VARCHAR(20)

Comment: @B001 she wants to declare a table variable

Comment: **Which** SQL? MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, or something else? Please [edit] your post to tag it. @Valerica No, though not worded clearly, the code shows that the question is how to select from a table having a dynamic name, which is taken from a variable. Once the DBMS is tagged, it will be trivial to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Table names can't be passed as parameters like that.

Comment: It's MySQL. Edited my question.

Its not a duplicate question, I like to call a table in mysql.

Comment: You're asking how to `select` from a table whose name you get from a variable. That is precisely what the other question asks. If others are interpreting the wrong meaning from your question, that's because you're not explaining it well.

Comment: Your wording asks how to create a table variable. Your code asks how to select from a table whose name is stored in a variable. Choose one. And see why you need to tag your DBMS at the outset? Three people have posted off-topic answers, falsely assuming you're using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

in sqlserver at least

```
declare @l_table varchar(100) = 'a'
declare @l_sql varchar(100) = 'select count(*) from '+@l_table
exec (@l_sql)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear. But this is how you declare a Table Variable in T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE (
JOB_NAME VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES ('A171107001')

select JOB_NAME from @TBL
```

After your edit I could see you are using MySQL.

Anyways, you are asking how to declare a table variable and it seems you are expecting how to select from a certain table, which it's name comes from a variable.